How to disable logical processors in OpenBSD?
It is well known that OpenBSD disables hyper-threading by default. However, htop shows 16 CPUs: 8 online and 8 offline, which takes extra space on the screen and is not very informative.

Moreover, sysctl also sees 16 logical CPUs. This doesn't make sense to me: with hyperthreading disabled, it's an 8-core 8-thread processor, so I should see 8 physical/logical CPUs.
$ sysctl hw
hw.machine=amd64
hw.model=AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics
hw.ncpu=16
hw.byteorder=1234
hw.pagesize=4096
hw.disknames=sd0:6d1abdce154d2fc8
hw.diskcount=1
hw.sensors.cpu0.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu2.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu4.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu6.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu8.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu10.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu12.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.cpu14.frequency0=3900000000.00 Hz
hw.sensors.ksmn0.temp0=83.12 degC (Tctl)
hw.sensors.it0.temp0=83.00 degC
hw.sensors.it0.temp1=49.00 degC
hw.sensors.it0.temp2=200.00 degC
hw.sensors.it0.fan0=0 RPM
hw.sensors.it0.fan1=3835 RPM
hw.sensors.it0.fan2=2986 RPM
hw.sensors.it0.volt0=1.74 VDC (VCORE_A)
hw.sensors.it0.volt1=1.62 VDC (VCORE_B)
hw.sensors.it0.volt2=2.67 VDC (+3.3V)
hw.sensors.it0.volt3=3.71 VDC (+5V)
hw.sensors.it0.volt4=10.69 VDC (+12V)
hw.sensors.it0.volt5=-3.24 VDC (-12V)
hw.sensors.it0.volt6=0.57 VDC (-5V)
hw.sensors.it0.volt7=3.68 VDC (+5VSB)
hw.sensors.it0.volt8=2.16 VDC (VBAT)
hw.cpuspeed=3200
hw.setperf=100
hw.vendor=AZW
hw.product=SER
hw.version=Default string
hw.serialno=A58003LH80340
hw.uuid=00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
hw.physmem=13840232448
hw.usermem=13840216064
hw.ncpufound=16
hw.allowpowerdown=1
hw.perfpolicy=manual
hw.smt=0
hw.ncpuonline=8
hw.power=1
hw.ucomnames=

How do I disable logical processors, so that each "CPU" is a physical processor?

Disable hyperthreading from BIOS/EFI. OpenBSD just put them offline

@RomeoNinov Thanks for the advice! If you can make it into an answer I will upvote and accept it.

Symmetric Multithreading, or "Why are only half of my CPUs used?"

Availability of hyperthreading is managed from BIOS/EFI. What OpenBSD do is to put offline the processor(s)/thread(s). So You should do it in BIOS/EFI by disabling hyperthreading  option.
